# Sass pre-processing using Webpack Encore: how to add sass options?

Tags: symfony, webpack, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to configure Webpack Encore to integrate Foundation into our project. At this [page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/css-preprocessors.html), it is said that Sass options can be passed into Encore using something like:

```
Encore
    // ...
    .enableSassLoader(function(sassOptions) {
        // https://github.com/sass/node-sass#options
        // options.includePaths = [...]
    });
;
```

How to pass Sass options such as the following (ie, the path to the scss folder of Foundation) in my config?

```
var sassOptions = {
    includePaths: 'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'
};
```

I'm new to Sass & Webpack. I'm probably missing smthg obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is that includePaths should be an array. If you do this, it should work:

```
var sassOptions = {
    includePaths: ['node_modules/foundation-sites/scss']
};
Encore
    // ...
    .enableSassLoader(function(sassOptions) {
        // https://github.com/sass/node-sass#options
        // options.includePaths = [...]
    });
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this already?

```
.enableSassLoader(function(sassOptions) {
    options.includePaths = ['node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'];
});
```

OR

```
.enableSassLoader(function(sassOptions) {
   sassOptions.includePaths = ['node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @bawun. Actually it is working now without passing any sassOptions (I just add .enableSassLoader() of course). I'm confused because I can't reproduce the problem I had some months ago...